# How can I randomize Image size

Tags: image-processing, processing, image-resizing

Thank you to the people who previously helped me, I have managed to work a lot on my generative business cards assignment.

I want to randomly resize 9 images in processing but can't seem to find a good example on the internet on how to do it. The size of the images is 850x550 which is also the background size.

Does anyone know a good and easy to follow tutorial? or could give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say you have stored an image in a [PImage](https://processing.org/reference/PImage.html) object, `image`
you can generate two [random](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html) integers for the `img_width` and `img_height` of the image and then `resize()` the `image` using [resize()](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_resize_.html) method

```
int img_width = foor(random(min_value, max_value));
int img_height = floor(random(min_value, max_value));
    
image.resize(img_width, img_height); //this simple code resizes the image to any dimension
```

or if you want to keep the same [aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)), then you can use this approach

```
//first set either of width or height to a random value
int img_width = floor(random(min_value, max_value));
    
//then proportionally calculate the other dimension of the image
float ratio = (float) image.width/image.height;
int img_height = floor(img_width/ratio);
    
image.resize(img_width, img_height);
```

You can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6YB9x6f23CBftiyx0u_5sO9) out YouTube playlist for some tutorials of image processing.

Answer (score 2):

The [Processing's documentation on the image() method](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html) covers this.

I still wrote you some skeleton code to demonstrate:

[image: Resizing beans!]

```
PImage img;
int w, h;
float scaleModifier = 1;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  img = loadImage("bean.jpeg");
  w = img.width;
  h = img.height;
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  image(img, 0, 0, w, h); // here is the important line
}

// Every click will resize the image
void mouseClicked() {
  scaleModifier += 0.1;
  if (scaleModifier > 1) {
    scaleModifier = 0.1;
  }
  
  w = (int)(img.width * scaleModifier);
  h = (int)(img.height * scaleModifier);
}
```

What's important to know is the following:

image() has 2 signatures:

1. image(img, a, b)
2. image(img, a, b, c, d)

Where the following applies:

1. img => the PImage for your image
2. a => x coordinate where to draw the image
3. b => y coordinate where to draw the image
4. c => the image's width (if it's different from the image's width, this implies a resize)
5. d => the image's height (also implies a resize if it's different from the "real" height)

Have fun!